# What is dx with u-substitution

Tags: calculus

I have to evaluate the following integral: $\int 4x(x^2-4)^3\,\mathrm dx$. Using [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/system-of-equations-calculator/%5Cint4x%5Cleft(x%5E%7B2%7D-4%5Cright)%5E%7B3%7D), it says I need to do a u-substitution at $x^2-4$. It gives the two hints:
$$\mathrm du = 2x,\quad \mathrm dx = \frac{1}{2x}$$

My question is, how was $\mathrm dx$ determined? How did we get $1/2x$? Can the answer please not be abstract and instead show me how we flipped $\mathrm du$? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some errors. With $u=x^2-4$ we get

$$ \frac{du}{dx}=2x$$

and therefore

$$dx= \frac{du}{2x}.$$

Comment: Thank's Fred, I now see it with algebra.

Answer (score 1):

With the substitution $$u= x^2 -4,$$

$$du = 2xdx$$

so that $$dx = \frac{du}{2x}.$$

We can now write and evaluate the integral as:

$$ \int 4x (x^2-4)^3 dx = 2 \int u^3 \, du = \frac{1}{2} u^4 + \textrm{ const.} = \frac{1}{2} (x^2-4)^4 + \textrm{ const.}$$